# Ionic spinners (Animated Loader) getting stuck while localstorage is used

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have implemented **ionic spinners (Animated Loader)** in the application and also I am using **localstorage** to save the data.

When the application communicates with the server ionic spinner works properly, that is it renders smoothly **without getting stuck**. Once the communication with the server is done and the downloaded **data needs to be inserted (saved)** in the localstorage the **spinner gets stuck (does not render properly)**.

In different blogs what I have observed is that localstorage does not render UI properly while data is getting inserted(saved).

Kindly let me know is there **any work around for this problem** or is there any other way of implementing animated loader (Ionic Spinner)

Below is the code that I have implemented

```
app.factory('LoaderService', ['$ionicLoading', '$timeout', function ($ionicLoading, $timeout) {
    return {
        show: function () {
            var templateVal = "<ion-spinner icon='android'></ion-spinner>";
            $ionicLoading.show({
                animation: 'fade-in',
                showBackdrop: true,
                minWidth: 200,
                showDelay: false,
                template: templateVal
            });
        },
        hide: function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, 300);            
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Are you using sync or Async call for saving data?

Comment: I am using Async call to save the downloaded data.

Comment: Did you find any solution or work-around @ShashankHS ?

Comment: No did not find a solution. As spinners cant be shown, I am displaying Loading message.